# compositng: when I use an alpha over node only one layer shows up

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I have a render in cycles that I want to use as a still shot but I'm having trouble with compositing layers. I have three separate layers all showing different objects, but when I use an alpha over node only one layer shows up

in-case this is a simple problem I'll keep this post short, but if anyone need's SS then I can provide them

thanks

Link to Blend File: http://puu.sh/pvqXT/3fe1d73a82.zip

Comment: Are you sure you turned on the '`Transparent`' checkbox on '`Film`' section on '`Render`' property button? Otherwise the layers won't be rendered with transparent background.

Comment: please add more information. [edit] your question and add images of your current setup so that we can understand better what the issue is. Please clarify: Do the layers have an alpha channel? Is film transparent enabled in the properties window? Please help us understand what the elements are so that we can help you better. Post your compositing nodes and any information that could be relevant. To get better answers don't wait to be asked for information.

Comment: sorry I was afk for a while, link to the blend file is now available, any help would be immensely appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image renders properly when you select "Transparent' within the Cycles 'Film' section.... In the Blender file available for download, it is unchecked...

When checked, this is the result I get... and nice sparks!

[image]

Sorry... was not sure if it was in or out....  Is this as you intended? See Gears6 blend file... if this is correct, the issue was in the node tree.... but, if not, I misunderstood. :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't solve my issue , since at the end of the cord there was a globe being lit. I tried ticking transparent as well but it doesn't show the light bulb. You'll find it in one of the render layers along with the compositor nodes to make it glow

Comment: Hope you saw my new file.... does that address it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't have the chance to check it out until now. It works perfectly thank you so much :D